# What stats are listed at the bottom of a default byobu session?

Tags: command-line, byobu

I recently logged in to my media center via ssh because it was having issues, and noticed at stat at the bottom of my terminal in red with exclamation marks next to it, but cannot seem to guess what it is signaling.  The 5 stats furthest to the right  seem to be number of processors, processor speed, ram? size, amount of ram in use, date.  One over from that appears to be up-time, but I can't figure out the rest of the stats.

### What stats are displayed at the bottom of this byobu system?

[image]

Comment: @DKBose which part?

Comment: Have you tried `man byobu`? I think I read something about the default stats there.

Comment: @virtualxtc Did my answer help?

Comment: sorry about that - never got a notification you had answered (or did when I was in a super rush)

Comment: No worries, glad to help, and thanks for the accept! (Also, I didn't get a notification for your response, because you need to @ tag me!) Cheers.

Comment: @PabloBianchi Not really, I'm asking about all the numbers, that question only asks about the #! one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the (online) [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/byobu.1.html)

```
STATUS NOTIFICATIONS

       byobu supports a number of unique and interesting status  notifications
       across  the  lowest  two lines in the screen.  Each status notification
       item  is  independently  configurable,  enabled  and  disabled  by  the
       configuration utility.  The guide below helps identify each status item
       (in alphabetical order):
```

...

```
updates_available - the number of  updates  available  on  the  system;
       displayed  in  the  lower  bar  toward the right in white text on a red
       background with  a  trailing  '!'  sign;  if  any  updates  are  marked
       'security  updates',  then  there  will  be  a  total  of  two trailing
       exclamation points, '!!'
```

Comment: Or, simply hit `F9` and see which Status Notifiations are currently enabled (in this order).